# NASHORN $EXEC issue with sed

Tags: java, sed, nashorn

I am trying to execute below command with NASHORN, to pull out a section of log -

```
$EXEC("sed '1,/Token to find:/d;/Another token to find:/,$d' /path/to/log/file.log")
```

But it ends with -

> Exit Code:1, Error Msg::sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown
>   command: `''

Trying the same on Linux command prompt,
below (with single quote ') it is able to pull out the log section -

```
sed '1,/Token to find:/d;/Another token to find:/,$d' /path/to/log/file.log
```

On the other hand changing the quotes (""), I get the same error -

```
sed "1,/Token to find:/d;/Another token to find:/,$d" /path/to/log/file.log
```

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `

Any idea what is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

After trying different combinations with sed " / ' etc.  - it looks like due to multiple scripting expressions (JavaScript/Linux Shell Script & sed command itself!) i am getting into this trouble.

> As a workaround i have moved expression into a text file and provided
>   sed its location  -

```
sed --file=/sed/expression/file /path/to/log/file.log
```

or

```
$EXEC("sed --file=/sed/expression/file /path/to/log/file.log");
var output=$OUT
var exitErrorMsg="Exit Code:" + $EXIT + ", Error Msg::" + $ERR
```

It now works like charm!